# filter array with same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to find all employees(EmpID) with same projects(ProjectID), data will be dynamic, this array is for example.

```
[
  { EmpID: '143,', ProjectID: '12,', DateFrom: '2013-11-01,', DateTo: '2014-01-05\r' },
  { EmpID: '218,', ProjectID: '10,', DateFrom: '2012-05-16,', DateTo: 'NULL\r' },
  { EmpID: '143,', ProjectID: '10,', DateFrom: '2009-01-01,', DateTo: '2011-04-27' },
];
```

I want this array to be ->

```
[
  { EmpID: '218,', ProjectID: '10,', DateFrom: '2012-05-16,', DateTo: 'NULL\r' },
  { EmpID: '143,', ProjectID: '10,', DateFrom: '2009-01-01,', DateTo: '2011-04-27' },
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array of objects by duplicate and property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522111/how-to-filter-array-of-objects-by-duplicate-and-property)

Comment: What is the business logic for duplicates - which one is chosen? The first one?

Comment: I want to find all Employees(EmpID) with same projects(ProjectId).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
const projectEmployees = employees.filter( emp => emp.ProjectID === '12' );
```

See [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the gory details.

Or... roll your own:

```js
function selectEmployeesByProjectId( employees, id ) {
  let projectEmployees = [];
  for ( const emp of employees ) {
    if ( emp.ProjectID === id ) {
      projectEmployees.push(emp);
    }
  }
  return projectEmployees;
}
```

If your data is truly dynamic and you don't know its true shape, other than it's a list of objects, just make your function flexible, something like the following. [But you'll still need to know what property or properties to match against to do your filtering.

```js
function selectMatchingObjects( listOfObjects, isWanted ) {
  return listOfObjects.filter( isWanted );
}
```

where `isWanted` is a function that accepts an object and returns a boolean `true` if the object is to be kept, or `false` if the object is to be discarded.

Once you have that you can do something like

```
function selectEmployeesByProject( employees , projectIdKey , projectId ) {
  const isWanted = emp = emp[projectIdKey] === projectId;
  return employees.filter( isWanted );
}
```

And then

```
const employees = getMySomeDynamicEmployees();
. . .
const projectEmployees = selectEmployeesByProject(employees, 'ProjectId', '10');
```

Comment: Yes, but the data in the array is dynamic and I don't know what it will be. I have to create a function for dynamic data.

Comment: Then update your question to be more clear. @dani

Comment: This is the easiest way to achieve it, as it skips looking up the property. 
In terms of dynamic data and project_id, you should be able to pick the project_id from the first item in the array and use that as the parameter instead

Comment: @dani — see my amended answer. If something like that doesn't work, you need to better explains exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish. No matter what you do, you will somehow have to (1) identify the property or properties to filter on, and (2) decide what value or combination of values identifies the keepers.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `Array.reduce` to accomplish this

```js
// The "trick" is to pull out the first item and then use that as the match candidate
const [head, ...tail] = [{ EmpId: 1 }, { EmpId: 2 }, { EmpId: 1 }]

const output = tail.reduce(
  (acc, b) => {
    if (acc.map(o => o.EmpId).includes(b.EmpId)) {
      acc.push(b)
    }
    return acc
  },
  [head]
)
```